About the function configureServiceManager in class ServiceManagerConfig in ZF2
I am reading thre sources code of ZF2.I met the class ServiceManagerConifg.I can't understand the function of the Function configureServiceManager.
class ServiceManagerConfig implements ConfigInterface
{
/\* Services that can be instantiated without factories \* @var array\*/
protected $invokables = array('SharedEventManager' =\> 'Zend\\EventManager\\SharedEventManager', );  
protected $factories = array(                     /\* Service factories  \*@var array */
'EventManager'  =\> 'Zend\\Mvc\\Service\\EventManagerFactory',
'ModuleManager' =\> 'Zend\\Mvc\\Service\\ModuleManagerFactory',
);
protected $abstractFactories = array();           /Abstract factories   \* @var array*/
protected $aliases = array(                    / Aliases  \* @var array */
'Zend\\EventManager\\EventManagerInterface' =\> 'EventManager', );
/Shared services，* Services are shared by default; this is primarily to indicate services that should NOT be shared @var array  */
protected $shared = array(
'EventManager' =\> false,
);
/* Constructor
\* Merges internal arrays with those passed via configuration \* @param  array $configuration */
public function \__construct(array $configuration = array())
{
if (isset($configuration\['invokables'\])) {
$this-\>invokables = array_merge($this-\>invokables, $configuration\['invokables'\]);
}
if (isset($configuration\['factories'\])) {
$this-\>factories = array_merge($this-\>factories, $configuration\['factories'\]);
}
if (isset($configuration\['abstract_factories'\])) {
$this-\>abstractFactories = array_merge($this-\>abstractFactories, $configuration\['abstract_factories'\]);
}
if (isset($configuration\['aliases'\])) {
$this-\>aliases = array_merge($this-\>aliases, $configuration\['aliases'\]);
}
if (isset($configuration\['shared'\])) {
$this-\>shared = array_merge($this-\>shared, $configuration\['shared'\]);
}
}
/* Configure the provided service manager instance with the configuration in this class.
\* In addition to using each of the internal properties to configure the service manager, also adds an initializer to inject
\*ServiceManagerAware and ServiceLocatorAware classes with the service manager.
\* @param  ServiceManager $serviceManager
\* @return void \*/
public function configureServiceManager(ServiceManager $serviceManager)
{
foreach ($this-\>invokables as $name =\> $class) {
$serviceManager-\>setInvokableClass($name, $class);
}
foreach ($this-\>factories as $name =\> $factoryClass) {
$serviceManager-\>setFactory($name, $factoryClass);
}
foreach ($this-\>abstractFactories as $factoryClass) {
$serviceManager-\>addAbstractFactory($factoryClass);
}
foreach ($this-\>aliases as $name =\> $service) {
$serviceManager-\>setAlias($name, $service);
}
foreach ($this-\>shared as $name =\> $value) {
$serviceManager-\>setShared($name, $value);
}
$serviceManager-\>addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($serviceManager) {
if ($instance instanceof EventManagerAwareInterface) {
if ($instance-\>getEventManager() instanceof EventManagerInterface) {
$instance-\>getEventManager()-\>setSharedManager(
$serviceManager-\>get('SharedEventManager')
);
} else {
$instance-\>setEventManager($serviceManager-\>get('EventManager'));
}
}
});
$serviceManager-\>addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($serviceManager) {
if ($instance instanceof ServiceManagerAwareInterface) {
$instance-\>setServiceManager($serviceManager);
}
});

        $serviceManager->addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($serviceManager) {
            if ($instance instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface) {
                $instance->setServiceLocator($serviceManager);
            }
        });
        $serviceManager->setService('ServiceManager', $serviceManager);
        $serviceManager->setAlias('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface', 'ServiceManager');
        $serviceManager->setAlias('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager', 'ServiceManager');
    }

}

The use in class ServiceManager
<?php
namespace Zend\ServiceManager;
use ReflectionClass;

class ServiceManager implements ServiceLocatorInterface
{
        /**@#+ Constants */
    const SCOPE_PARENT = 'parent';
    const SCOPE_CHILD = 'child';
protected $canonicalNames = array();        /*Lookup for canonicalized names. * @var array*/
    protected $allowOverride = false;           /** @var bool*/    
    protected $invokableClasses = array();       /* @var array*/    
    protected $factories = array();             /* @var string|callable|\Closure|FactoryInterface[] */    
    protected $abstractFactories = array();      /* @var AbstractFactoryInterface[]  */    
    protected $delegators = array();           /* @var array[] */    
    protected $pendingAbstractFactoryRequests = array();   /* @var array */    
    protected $lastAbstractFactoryUsed = null;            /* @var string*/    
    protected $lastCanonicalNameUsed   = null;         /*@var string */    
    protected $shared = array();                       /* @var array */   
    protected $instances = array();                     /* Registered services and cached values * @var array*/    
    protected $aliases = array();                      /* @var array*/   
    protected $initializers = array();                   /* @var array*/    
    protected $peeringServiceManagers = array();      /* @var ServiceManager[] */    
    protected $shareByDefault = true;                /*Whether or not to share by default  *@var bool*/    
    protected $retrieveFromPeeringManagerFirst = false;     /** @var bool */    
    protected $throwExceptionInCreate = true;             /* @var bool Track whether not to throw exceptions during create()  */
                                                   /* @var array map of characters to be replaced through strtr */
    protected $canonicalNamesReplacements = array('-' => '', '_' => '', ' ' => '', '\\' => '', '/' => '');
    /*Constructor
     * @param ConfigInterface $config */
    public function __construct(ConfigInterface $config = null)
    {
        if ($config) {
            $config->configureServiceManager($this);
        }
    }
   

I has try to ask gpt.It told me that"This code is the configureServiceManager method, which is responsible for configuring the ServiceManager instance and setting up various services and their dependencies. The multiple configuration steps within the method ensure that the ServiceManager correctly registers services, aliases, factories, initializers, etc"
However,Isn't the ServiceManager used to manage services? Why, in the configuration of configureServiceManager (the configuration of the ServiceManager),it is used to ensure that the ServiceManager correctly registers services, aliases, factories, initializers, etc.?

Its the method responsible for iterating the services which is setup in your config files. The construct method of the same class get the application config passed to it and merges it with the default services listed in the class properties. After merging they are passed to this method to be iterated and passed to the appropriate method of the service manager. Each of those properties ie invokables, factories etc correspond to the keys in the configuration arrays.
